# Bootstrap navbar not opening on mobile screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying the below HTML to add a navbar on screen. When I resize the window to the extent of showing the toggle button, clicking on it, does nothing. Anything missing in the html?

Thanks

```
        <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#proj-navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Name</a>
          </div>
          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="proj-navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Initiation</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Implementation</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Close Out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have properly linked the css and js files of bootstrap. These are required for the collapsible menu to work.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.3.0/bootstrap-3.3.0-dist.zip

If you want to minimize your javascript files, you can just use the collapsible plugin, because the responsive menu depends on it:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse